# React-navigation, cannot pass title to header

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I cannot see the title in my header:

```
const withHeader = (
    screen: Function,
    routeName: string,
    Header
): StackNavigator =>
    createStackNavigator({
        [routeName]: {
            screen,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation, routeName }) => ({
                header: props => <Header {...props} />,
                title: routeName,
                headerMode: "screen",
                layoutPreset: "right"
            })
        }
    });
```

`this.props` doesnt contain the title prop.

How can I pass the title to my header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `static navigationOptions` in you Class/Screen:

```
class TargetScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Your Title',
  };

  /* render function, etc */
}
```